# Get Events From A Calendar Using Google's NodeJS OAuth2 Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using this nodejs google library: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#getting-supported-apis

Here is the api call so far (in the actual code I have my real secrets and ids):

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    "MY_CLIENT_ID",
    "MY_CLIENT_SECRET",
    "http://localhost:3000"
);

export default function handler(req, res) {
    res.status(200).json(oauth2Client);
}
```

That outputs

```
{"_events":{},"_eventsCount":0,"transporter":{},"credentials":{},"eagerRefreshThresholdMillis":300000,"forceRefreshOnFailure":false,"certificateCache":{},"certificateExpiry":null,"certificateCacheFormat":"PEM","refreshTokenPromises":{},"_clientId":"MY_CLIENT_ID","_clientSecret":"MY_CLIENT_SECRET","redirectUri":"http://localhost:3000"}
```

Does anybody know how to use that oauth2Client to get a list of events from a specific calendar? I can't find any information on that anywhere.

The info I do find uses something called gapi, but this is what is on Google's documentation.

### Edit

I tried Ricardo's suggestion but it said it could not load the default credentials:

```
const authClient = await auth.getClient();
```

Is there a way to specify the default credentials in the code without doing it via the command line via

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Comment: To be clear, the examples I find talk about letting a user get authenticated and showing their calendar events. I don't want to do that. I want to pick a calendar on the backend that I will then show to my users.

Comment: I was running my quick-start sample to find the 10 upcoming events, that uses `events.list ` the way that library calls the function, i found one that was linked: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/calendar/classes/Resource$Events.html#list  // One key thing is the fact that as long as you are a Super Admin you should be able to change the "CalendarId" to any of the calendars of the organization, as long as it is being run by the Super Admin. I have a sample of the normal quickstart that I use any email address from users of my organization that I can share.

Comment: Awesome, I gotta go but I will be trying the stuff from that link in the morning.

Comment: Using that example didn't work. It kept telling me the request didn't have a valid API key.